# MongoLab MongoDB login failed error

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I'm getting this error when trying to login to MongoLab database via command line in Ubuntu

```
> 2015-07-02T13:44:05.682-0400 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed  
>2015-07-02T13:44:05.694-0400 E QUERY    Error: error doing query: failed  
at DBQuery._exec (src/mongo/shell/query.js:83:36)  
at DBQuery.hasNext (src/mongo/shell/query.js:240:10)  
at DBCollection.findOne (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:187:19)  
at DB.runCommand (src/mongo/shell/db.js:58:41)  
at DB.isMaster (src/mongo/shell/db.js:680:51)  
at DB._getDefaultAuthenticationMechanism (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1227:27)
at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1252:33)  
at (auth):6:8  
at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:83  
exception: login failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that your client supports the version of MongoDB your server is running. If you're using one of our experimental databases, they were recently upgraded to MongoDB version 3.0 an its new SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mechanism. Connecting to these databases now requires the 3.0 Mongo shell or a driver that supports SCRAM-SHA-1.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers

If you have any questions, feel free to contact us at support@mongolab.com and we'd be happy to help.

Regards,

Jared